# Calculate input from textfield in a loop

Tags: xcode, loops, textfield

How can I calculate a textfield in a loop?  I have a textfield in a loop and I want to calculate the input in another textfield.

```
x = 36;     y = 0;   w = 36      h = 25 ;

moretext = 0 ;

for (moretext=0; moretext<5; moretext ++) {
    textFiled1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
    textFiled1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    textFiled1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textFiled1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica " size:(8)];
    x+=36 ;

    [self.view addSubview:textFiled1];
}
```

I want to have the TOTAL for the textfield1 loop input showing in textfield2

```
textFiled2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 0, 36, 25)];
textFiled2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
textFiled2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textFiled2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica " size:(8)];

[self.view addSubview:textFiled2];
```

Comment: numbers input in textfield1 and show the total in textfield2

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol you can get updates from the UITextField as people type. `textFieldDidEndEditing:` will tell you when someone is done editing a textfield as well.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: thanks , But can you write it for me in codes to make it more easy to understand cos i know how to implementing the UITextFieldDelegate protocol but i dont know how to make the textFieldDidEndEditing.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to revise the code:
At the time of allocating multiple UITextField objects, you need to store these in some array like this.

```
myArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
UITextField *textFiled1;

int moretext = 0 ;

for (moretext=0; moretext<5; moretext ++, y=y+50) {
    textFiled1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
    textFiled1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    textFiled1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textFiled1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica " size:(8)];
    textFiled1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",y];
    //x+=36 ;
    [myArray addObject:textFiled1];
    [self.view addSubview:textFiled1];
    NSLog(@"view Did Load called");
}
```

Later to do the total you need to traverse through array and extract the text field value and accumulate in some variable like this.

```
- (int) calc {
int total=0;
int counter;
for (counter=0; counter<5; counter ++) {
    UITextField *field1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:counter];
    total = total + [field1.text intValue];
    NSLog(@"value: %d",[field1.text intValue]);

}

return total;
}
```

Comment: thanks , but i dont want to Calculate the frame for textfield .

i want to Calculate the input numbers in the textfield .